# Using @font-face results in text having height of 0 on Mac

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I have a website with a custom font (Gotham Book). All containers like this:

```
<span>TEXT IN GOTHAM </span>
```

Get height of 0 on Mac (Chrome and Safari, not on Chrome for Win). Same containers work fine with other fonts like Arial, or Roboto or whatever.

The font is in the CSS like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gotham Book';
  src: url("/assets/fonts/GothamBook.ttf")
}
```

Do i have to specify something else?

Comment: Same problem, font is gotham. The height is 0 in IOS and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I think your font was not getting loaded for some reason and you need to debug that on mac (you should check your console for any error)

I would suggest to link all font file format which you have got with that font
, see below code for example

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

I also suggest to add fallback font as if your font was not loaded it will take other font

```
font-family: 'MyWebFont', Arial, sans-serif;
```

Comment: the font was correctly loaded as seen via network-tab and absence of any console-errors. Also the font appears correctly, it just has no height.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in this case may be the Gotham Book font.  Running into a similar issue but it goes away with any other font (even Gotham Book Light, etc. fixes it)